# JQuery Mobile slide transition works in reverse but not forward

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a web app with the 'multi-page' paradigm, trying to transition between DIVs that are on the same page using the "slide" transition.

I have two functions that are triggered upon a swipe or keyboard left/right:

```
function navnext(next) {
  console.log('(next) navigating to ' + next);
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + next, {
    transition: "slide",
    allowSamePageTransition: true
  });
}

function navprev(prev) {
  console.log('(prev) navigating to ' + prev);
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + prev, {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: true,
    allowSamePageTransition: true
  });
}
```

The reverse transition works properly. The current active page slides to the right as the previous page slides in from the left.

Using the forward transition, the current active page slides out, but a blank white page slides in. Once the white page slides in, the content flashes on. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what could be causing this to only happen in one direction.

*EDIT*: After playing around, I was able to eliminate the issue by removing the header. I get the sense that I'm not using external headers correctly.

Here's my header code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="d">
  <div class="icon-up-arrow">
    <img src="/static/img/up-arrow-white.png">
  </div>
  <h1 id="header_text" class="smallcaps"></h1>
</div>
```

And the following JS runs at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```
$( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar({ theme: "d" });
$( "[data-role='footer']" ).toolbar({ theme: "d" });
```

Comment: Are you dynamically filling in the next page upon swipe, or is it static content that is already there? Are you running any code on pagecreate, pageshow, etc?

Comment: The content is static, and I'm updating the header and footer using the `pagecontainerbeforeshow` event. But disabling that code doesn't help.

Comment: @ezanker: After playing around, I was able to eliminate the issue by removing the header. I get the sense that I'm not using the external header correctly. I'm putting my header HTML in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Setting data-position="fixed" on the header seems to get around the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w4tuv0dm/

Comment: I must have missed that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `data-position="fixed"` to my header solved the problem. Thanks @ezanker.